# YYYYMMDD HHMNSC конвертировать в YYYY-MM-DD HH:MN:SC

Tags: строки, datetime

Файл имеет большое кол-во дат в виде текста, все эти даты нужно конвертировать в формат даты

Comment: python? добавьте в вопрос примеры дат и ожидание на выходе?

Answer (score 1):

**Если это `python`**, то можно конвертировать строку в дату, например, так:

```
from datetime import datetime

oldformat = '20201221 215534'
datetimeobject = datetime.strptime(oldformat,'%Y%m%d %H%M%S') #формат даты

newformat = datetimeobject.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print newformat
```

Изначальная строка (случайная, для примера): `20201221 215534`
Вывод: `2020-12-21 21:55:34`

**Если это `Java`**, то

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat oldformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HHmmss");
try{
    date = oldformat.parse("20201010 193723"); // формат даты
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
SimpleDateFormat newformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(newformat.format(date));
```

Изначальная строка (случайная, для примера): `20201010 193723`
Вывод: `2020-10-10 19:37:23`